# Drawing a mountain look figure in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am not sure where I can start from and is it easy to draw a figure below using latex?

[image]

Comment: yes. take a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-distributions/ for example

Comment: @EladDen, Thanks. Not easy....

Comment: It _is_ very easy for this image. However, this site is not a `please do this for me` service. So please do some work first and then post a concrete question. Here is how I'd solve it.  First define coordinates for Start, End, A, B, C, D and E (D and E the valleys), then use bezier curves (see the `.. controls ..` tiks syntax) to draw the curves, lastly learn to find curve intersections to the the two missing end points for the dashed curves. Everything you need is on the site in other questions.

Comment: @daleif. Sorry, I do not mean to ask for this. I just struggle reading example which is very complicated, and I have no way to start. For table, i can start from the table which i had draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a sequence of `to[out=0,in=180]` paths with some `looseness`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[very thick,name path=hills] (0,0) coordinate(O) -- ++ (65:5)
 to[out=65,in=180] (3.5,6) coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A)
 to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.4] ++ (2.25,-5.5) coordinate (v1)
 to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.4] ++ (2.5,3.5) coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C)
 to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.4] ++ (1.75,-1.75) coordinate (v2)
 to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.5] ++ (2.5,2.5) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B)
 to[out=0,in=110,looseness=0.4] ++ (1.2,-1.75)
 -- (15,0) coordinate (F);
 \draw[thick,blue,shorten >=2mm,shorten <=2mm] (O) -- (F);
 \foreach \X/\Y in {A/O,B/v1,C/v2}
 {\draw[thick,latex-latex] (\X) -- node[midway,fill=white] {$\X$} (\X|-\Y);}
 \path[name path=v1] (v1) -- (F|-v1);
 \draw[dashed,name intersections={of=hills and v1}] (v1) -- (intersection-2);
 \path[name path=v2] (v2) -- (O|-v2);
 \draw[dashed,name intersections={of=hills and v2}] (v2) -- (intersection-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cat. Thanks. you are brilliant! How can I draw a line (blue) line at the bottom of the wave?

Comment: @aan Added.....

Comment: Do the `intersection` load the `calc` library, or does the `|-` syntax use not need the `calc` library? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar The latter. `|-` is built in and does not require you to load a library.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat a following up question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530121/how-to-add-a-tail-and-beginning-of-a-mountain